# logrotate broken yet not error message

Tags: linux, logging, logrotate, log-rotation

It seems like there are quite a few common issues with logrotate not doing what it suppose to and as it happens I am in the same boat.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24G Jun 23 01:15 A10.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 18 12:22 A110.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18G Jun 23 01:15 A11223.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jun 22 00:00 A115.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18G Jun 23 01:15 A11.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.1G Jun 23 01:15 A202.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.5G Jun 23 01:15 A216.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 496M Jun 23 01:15 A221.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18G Jun 23 01:15 A235.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 515M Jun 23 01:15 A236.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17G Jun 23 01:15 A404.log
```

Now the above output shows some files that are considerably large in size. Logrotate is supposed to run on a daily basis and rotate files daily and if the file is over 1GB

```
/var/log/tomcat/A*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 5
        compress
        maxsize 1G
        notifempty
        create 640 tomcat adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /etc/init.d/tomcat stop > /dev/null
                /etc/init.d/tomcat start > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

Executing the logrotate manually gives the following output

```
host:/usr/share/tomcat/logs# logrotate -f --verbose /etc/logrotate.d/rotateTomcat
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/rotateTomcat

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/tomcat/A*.log  forced from command line (5 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, log files >= 1073741824 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.
```

How come that it does not detect any log file in that directory above 1GB in size?

Comment: What is the content of the `/var/log/tomcat` directory?

Comment: @MichaelHampton its the very first code snippet A10,A110 etc. /var/log/tomcat is a symbolic link to /usr/share/tomcat/logs